# Null Hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, descriptive-statistics

A survey found that 70% of college professors believe that their online education courses are as good as or superior to courses that use traditional face-to face instruction.

What is the null hypothesis?

Comment: Hi Cita and welcome to the site. Is this a homework question? If so, could you please add the `self-study` tag as we treat those kind of questions differently. Thank you.

Comment: We welcome questions like this, @Cita, but we treat them differently. Please tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you are stuck, & we'll try to provide hints to get you unstuck. To better understand the process, you should read the [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for the `[self-study]` tag. Please edit your question to add this information, as simply listing your homework question & hoping someone will provide an answer for you is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 2):

Why does there need to be a null hypothesis?  Sometimes statistics is done just to estimate a value without the need to test.

And as a general rule, if you do feel the need to test, then the determination of the null hypothesis should come before any data collection, otherwise you may be looking at the [Texas Sharpshooter fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_sharpshooter_fallacy).

Comment: the teacher is asking for the null hypothesis, so lost at this point.

Comment: @Cita, if this is homework then you should at a minimum add the 'self-study' tag.  This question might be better for your teacher or TA.  As written it is a poor question, very vague, there are many null hypotheses that could be considered.  Is there more context?  an example in the text or lecture notes that is similar?

Answer (score 1):

I think that H0 should be OC >= TC where:

- OC = Quality of online education courses
- TC = Quality of courses that use traditional face-to face instruction

Comment: It is hard to understand what you might mean by this, because the survey appears to concern college professors and its statistic is a *proportion* giving a particular answer. It certainly is not a count or proportion of *courses.* How is this proportion of professors reflected in your answer?

Comment: I edited the post. What you might test is that the quality of OC is as good as or superior to courses that use traditional face-to face instruction. I don't think that you have to calculate it.

Comment: I still don't see how you can test for the quality of courses based on a survey of professors.  You might consider testing something about the professors' *opinions* of their courses, but obviously that's quite a different thing.

Comment: I agree with you, I had not explained it well

Answer (score -1):

The null hypothesis is what should normally be the case. Example is peter a thief? The null hypothesis is no, because it is not normal for someone to be a thief. The alternative is always what you believe should be the case. So the Null hypothesis from your question is that conventional teaching method is the best as against what the professors think (which is their thought not what should be normally)

Comment: Because I believe, with great regret, that every one of your statements is incorrect or misleading, I would like to invite you to support them with authoritative citations if you can.

Comment: Fisher 1971 The principle of experimentation.In Fisher's formulation, "the null hypothesis is never proved or established, but is possibly disproved. The null hypothesis is the default position.

Comment: Thank you--but I think you grievously misinterpret Fisher. "Default position" is correct but that does not equate--nor is rarely even the same as--"what should normally be the case," nor is it the negation of "what you believe should be the case," nor is it what professors happen (or not) to think.